# How to stop a thread that is suspended on a Bluetooth read

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

My app displays data from a steady stream of Bluetooth text input.

In Android 2.3.4, if I close the socket the read immediately throws an IO exception. In 2.2 is does only most of the time.

I am trying to stop the reading when onStop() is called. Then in onStart() I reconnect.

Is there a better way to kill the thread that is suspended on an inputStream read that is likely to work over all versions?

Thanks
TomZ

Comment: A thread is blocked on an IO socket read.  You close the socket from another thread.  I'm sorry, but I just have to ask - what sort of result were you expecting?  Throwing an exception is a reasonable response to having a socket connection ripped away. You can catch the exception and just deal with it.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted and expected, the exception. The problem is that 2.2 does not always throw it, it just hangs so I am looking for a better way out. From what I can tell, there is no way to have a Bluetooth socket read do a timeout. TomZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried interrupting the task and got bogged down in multiple types of exceptions depending on what it was doing at the time of the interrupt and getting compile errors that I was catching exceptions that it said could not be thrown. Even when I did get some working code, it still had reliability problems on Froyo (Galaxy S - Vibrant).

So I backed up and tried using InputStream.available in a loop with a short sleep and a check of a flag that is set to end the read task (so the task was never suspended except on the sleep). This worked great on various android versions.

It seems the trick is to not externally stop the thread but to let it detect the need to quit and return on it's own.

Seems a bit of a kludge, sort of polling the reads. But the code is now stable and the phone performance does not seem to suffer.